# Devexpress Project Converter v17.2 converting from v12 have error?

Tags: devexpress, converters, windows

When I use project converter v17 of Devexpress to convert my project and build again, I see this error:

```
    Error   3   The type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm' is defined in an assembly that is
not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DevExpress.Utils.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.
```

I spend hours to solve this, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your project still refers to version 12.1.  Probably, your main project refers to some other project/library that utilizes version 12.1. Such projects should be upgraded as well. Try running the Project Converter again and ensure that you included all referenced projects.

If this doesn't help, you can manually delete incorrect references and add required assemblies to your projects.